# My users query is bringing me all the data below the letter I type

Tags: firebase, react-native, search, google-cloud-firestore, textinput

I am trying to do a parameter search of an input and when I do my users search my query is bringing me all the data below the letter I type, can someone explain me what I am doing wrong ?

**Search Query**

```
const fetchUsers = (search) => {
        firebase.firestore()
            .collection('users')
            .orderBy('username')
            .startAt(search)
            .get()
            .then((snapshot) => {
                let users = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                    const data = doc.data();
                    const id = doc.id;
                    return { id, ...data }
                });
                setUsers(users);
            })
    }
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is the expecting behavior. The `startAt` (and it's siblings `startAfter`, `endAt`, and `endBefore`) operation allows you to get a *slice* of the data. So your current query tells the database to order the documents on their `username` field, and then *start returning* documents starting *at* `search` in the results.

What you want to do is find documents where `username` starts **with** the value you specify, which is a different operation. If you want to use the slice operators, you can do this by adding an `endAt`:

```
firebase.firestore()
    .collection('users')
    .orderBy('username')
    .startAt(search)
    .endAt(search+"\uf8ff")
```

The `\uf8ff` is just the last known Unicode character, so that gives you a slice of the data that starts *with* the `search` term.